# Add a List to another List that is either null or not null

Tags: c#, list, null, addrange

Consider the the piece of code below. I need to call the method `CreateOrAddToLists()` in a loop. First time the method is called the two lists `casedata.Cases` and `casedata.Documents` will be null, hence I can populate by assigning `cases` to `casedata.Cases` like this:

`casedata.Cases = cases;`

At any subsequent call to CreateOrAddToLists() lists `casedata.Cases` and `casedata.Documents` will not be null and I can add new data to the lists using AddRange():

`casedata.Cases.AddRange(cases);`

```
var casedata = new CaseData(); //contains lists to get populated

private void CreateOrAddToLists()
{   
    var cases = new List<Case>(); //gets data with from database
    var documents = new List<Document>(); //gets data with from database

    if (casedata.Cases == null)
    {
        casedata.Cases = cases;
    }
    else
    {
        casedata.Cases.AddRange(cases);
    }
    if (casedata.Documents == null)
    {
        casedata.Documents = documents;
    }
    else
    {
        casedata.Documents.AddRange(documents);
    }
}
```

Is there a better or neater way to do a null-check before `AddRange`? Can I do it in on line of code?

Comment: What exactly are you after? It seems okay to me?

Comment: `(casedata.Documents ?? (casedata.Documents = new List<Document>())).AddRange(documents);` - but I wouldn't say this is better or neater. Making code smaller doesn't necessarily make it better or more clever - making it readable is more important, because you are the one who will be maintaining it in future

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the constructor for `CaseData` instantiate the two list objects, then you'll be assured they won't be null and you can just use `AddRange`.

```
public CaseData()
{
    Cases = new List<Case>();
    Documents = new List<Document>();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It's more clear:

```
casedata.Cases = casedata.Cases ?? new List<Case>();
casedata.Cases.AddRange(cases);

casedata.Documents = casedata.Documents ?? new List<Document>();
casedata.Documents.AddRange(documents);
```

Comment: I have accepted the answer @Steve provided as it is the more correct answer, but for now in my own code I will use your answer because it is clear and useful and can be easily implemented.